# @var IS Null condition causing clustered index scans

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, indexing

I have a query

```
Select Column1, column2.... column30 
From Table 
Where (@var IS NULL OR Col1 = @var)
```

This can get resolved to a clustered index scan where every row in a table getting checked against this condition @var IS NULL and the index set up on the column Col1 is disregarded. Is there a way to re-write this query to enable the optimizer to use the index on col1? Thank you!

Comment: My guess is this is a procedure and you first ran said procedure where `@var` had the value `NULL`. Add the `RECOMPILE` option to your `OPTION` clause.

Comment: Some required reading: [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example), [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: For this simple example, you can use `UNION ALL` which will make use of the index if @var is supplied, i.e. `SELECT Column1, Column2 .... Column30 FROM Table WHERE Col1 = @Var UNION ALL SELECT Column1, Column2 .... Column30 FROM Table WHERE @Var IS NULL` - This requires no recompilation nor dynamic SQL. I assume however that your actual scenario involves more than one column, so it's back to either recompiling with each run, or dynamic SQL

Comment: Don't use such catch-all queries. That's *exactly* what can happen if the query is executed with a `null` the first time

Comment: To be clear it doesn't matter what order the parameter cases are compiled in here,. if you aren't using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` then SQL Server needs to generate an execution plan that will work correctly in both cases - and this will need a full scan. An execution plan compiled with a seek on `Col1 = @var` could not be cached and reused for the other case. This is not a parameter sniffing issue